# Mount ZFS pool before snapd starts

Tags: systemd, zfsonlinux, snap

I have a zpool that has a mountpoint at `/var`.  When I start my server up, the `snapd` service always throws a bunch of errors and fails to start because it attempts to mount a bunch of things from `/var` to `/snap` but it attempts the mounts before the `zpool` has been mounted so there's nothing in `/var` yet.

How can I get `snapd` to attempt these mounts after the zpool has been mounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with libvirtd wanting to start before ZFS had mounted its directory under `/var` and solved it with a systemd drop-in.

You can make an equivalent drop-in for `snapd.service`:

```
ubuntu@vmtest-ubuntu2004:~$ sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/snapd.service.d

ubuntu@vmtest-ubuntu2004:~$ cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/snapd.service.d/zfs.conf
[Unit]
Requires=zfs.target
After=zfs.target
EOF

ubuntu@vmtest-ubuntu2004:~$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

This causes systemd to wait to start snapd until ZFS has finished starting up.